# Excel process don´t close VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, exit

I saw my question popping up quite a few times, but none of the answer worked for me.. So let me introduce you to my Problem:
I run my Makro (just a single Sub) from an Word Document. As a helping hand I´ll open a new Excel file, format things from my clipboard in it and then bring it back to the Word file.
But after everything is done, nobody can see, that I used Excel.
BUT it wont close as a process, as I want it to. I tried every method I saw, but nothing seems to work:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' declare Excel Objects
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wbCalculator As Workbook
Dim wsCalculator As Worksheet

' initialize Excel Objects
Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
Set wbCalculator = Excel.Workbooks.Add
Set wsCalculator = wbCalculator.Sheets(1)

...
"My totally efficient and beautiful Code"
...

' Close Excel
wbCalculator.Saved = True
Set wsCalculator = Nothing
wbCalculator.Close False
Set wbCalculator = Nothing
appExcel.Quit
Set appExcel = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I hope you can help me out with this one:)

Comment: I am not sure if this help, but it is worth the try. 

Can you try `wbCalculator.Close SaveChanges:=False` instead of just `wbCalculator.Close False`?

Comment: Could it be that your *totally efficient and beautiful code* contains unqualified `Cells` calls? These would be implicitly creating an `Excel.Application` to which you hold no reference, thus have no way to tear down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to highlight two lines of code here:

```
Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
Set wbCalculator = Excel.Workbooks.Add
```

Here you can see that you created an object named `appExcel` and the intent is to use that object.  However, you then simply reference the `Excel` object model directly *instead of* `appExcel`.  This means you now have an extra Excel instance under the same process that you never again address or close.  Try changing it to:

```
Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
Set wbCalculator = appExcel.Workbooks.Add
```

Comment: Gah, there's the implicit `Excel.Application` instance.. totally missed it. Also possible that the OP's *totally efficient and beautiful code* implicitly references `Excel.Application` through unqualified `Worksheets`, `Names`, `Cells`, `Columns`, or `Rows` calls (unqualified `Range` would call into the Word object model).

Comment: Yeah, that's an excellent point too, definitely worth the OP looking into their code to make sure there aren't unqualified references, and that everything can be traced back to `appExcel`.

Comment: @tigeravatar You, Sir, are my hero for today.
That absolutely fixed it. Sometimes you are just too focused on the wrong spot... **All my thanks to you!**